# Is there a way to get one, unified, mapping from all indices under one alias?

Tags: javascript, python, elasticsearch, curl, elasticsearch-py

For example if I have 10 indices with similar names and they all alias to `test-index`, how would I get `test-index-1` `test-index-2` `test-index-3` `test-index-4`, `test-index-5`, `test-index-6`, `test-index-7`, `test-index-8`, `test-index-9`, and `test-index-10` to all point to the mapping in use currently when you to a `GET /test-index/_mapping`?

Comment: I initially misunderstood your problem. What is wrong with the response that you get with `GET /test-index/_mapping` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you define as  'unified' mapping - but you can always use wildcards in mapping request. For example : /test-inde*/_mapping would give mapping of all indices in that pattern .

Comment: This is the way I originally intended the problem. But then I realized he said that he's already using an alias `test-index` for all those indices, and he reported the command that I would expect as correct for getting all the mappings - i.e., `GET /test-index/_mapping`. My feeling is that he'd like to get all mappings merged into a single one associated to the alias, which, AFAIK, is just not possible